# Customized Error Response is not returned for Consumer side and throwing BAD REQUEST error for Spring Cloud Contract Tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-test, wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

I have producer & consumer projects for Spring cloud contract tests. I have success scenario based test cases and error scenario based test cases, which are working fine from consumer side. But, for the error scenario, instead of returning the customized error response & passing the test case in consumer side, it is throwing an exception in consumer project. Producer project both scenario generated test cases are fine.

Producer side groovy script:
As you can see I passed an invalid String value for accountId in the body instead of a Long value.

```
Contract.make {
    request {
        method PUT()
        urlPath("/api/v1/a")
        headers {
            contentType('application/json')
        }
        body("{\"accountId\": \"11332382Adg\" ,\"caseNumber\":\"CIS0005468\",\"representmentStartDate\":\"20181212\"}")

    }


    response {
        status 400
        headers {
            contentType('application/json')
        }

        body([

                "errorDescription": "invalid request or invalid date format"

        ])
    }
}
```

This below generated test case in target passes.
Generated Test case (this is success and passing) producer side

```
public class Rap extends SRAP {
@Test
    public void validate InvalidateRequest() throws Exception {
        // given:
            MockMvcRequestSpecification request = given()
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .body("{\"accountId\":\"11332382Adg\",\"caseNumber\":\"CIS0005468\",\"representmentStartDate\":\"20181212\"}");

        // when:
            ResponseOptions response = given().spec(request)
                    .put("/api/v1/a");

        // then:
            assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(400);
            assertThat(response.header("Content-Type")).matches("application/json.*");
        // and:
            DocumentContext parsedJson = JsonPath.parse(response.getBody().asString());
            assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['errorDescription']").isEqualTo("invalid request or invalid date format");
    }

}
```

Super class of Test, which gets extended by the subclass generated in target.This class has the error response I am using in the test case, where, whenever an excption is called, I call the buildErrorResponse() method, which will return customized error response.

```
`class SRAP{
public void setup() {


        StandaloneMockMvcBuilder standaloneMockMvcBuilder = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(findCaseController, ApiController, controllerExceptionAdvice);

        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(standaloneMockMvcBuilder);

        when(controllerExceptionAdvice.handleHttpMessageNotReadable(any(), any(), any(), any()))
                .thenReturn(
                        new ResponseEntity<>(
                                buildErrorResponse(),
                                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
                        )

                );
        when(controllerExceptionAdvice.handleMethodArgumentTypeMismatchException(any(), any()))
                .thenReturn(
                        new ResponseEntity<>(
                                buildErrorResponse(),
                                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
                        )
                );

private ErrorResponse buildErrorResponse() {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = ErrorResponse.builder().build();
        errorResponse.setErrorDescription("invalid request or invalid date format");
        return errorResponse;
    }


}
```

consumer side success Test case:

```
 @Test
    public void should_update_case_success() throws Exception {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                "http://localhost:8083/api/v1/a",
                HttpMethod.PUT,
                new HttpEntity<>("{\"accountId\":\"1112321\",\"caseNumber\":\"CIS1233\",\"representmentStartDate\":\"20181212\"}", httpHeaders), String.class);
        BDDAssertions.then(response.getStatusCodeValue()).isEqualTo(200);


    }
```

Consumer side Test case which is FAILING:I have given the invalid value for accountId, for it to fail and give me a customized error response

```
@Test
public void case_error() throws Exception {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                "http://localhost:8083/api/v1/a",
                HttpMethod.PUT,
                new HttpEntity<>("{\"accountId\":\"11332382Adg\",\"caseNumber\":\"CIS0005468\",\"representmentStartDate\":\"20181212\"}", httpHeaders), String.class);

        BDDAssertions.then(response.getStatusCodeValue()).isEqualTo(400);
        System.out.println("response " + response.getBody());
        BDDAssertions.then(response.getBody().equals("{\"errorDescription\":\"invalid request or invalid date format\"}"));
```

Even in the logs I get response matched for the Stubs-jar, but why is the test case failing ?:

```
Matched response definition:
{
  "status" : 400,
  "body" : "{\"errorDescription\":\"invalid request or invalid date format\"}",
  "headers" : {
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
  },
  "transformers" : [ "response-template" ]
}

Response:
HTTP/1.1 400
Content-Type: [application/json]`
```

The Error Test case in consumer side only passes if I passed , but I should be getting the customized error response

```
@Test(expected=HttpClientErrorException.class)
```

Expected Result: Customized error body should be returned & test case passed.

```
{ errorDescription: invalid request or invalid date format }
```

Actual result:`org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request`

Comment: That has nothing to do with Spring Cloud Contract as such. Stub Runner (via WireMock) returns exactly the response you expect. I guess you need to configure RestTemplate to properly. Can you set it up that it doesn't throw an exception on error and see if the response body was properly parsed?

Comment: Can you direct me to examples of consumer side test cases ? with error response or anything online ?

Comment: Maybe check https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/14633